# PyQt Windows Style adds dotted index line to QTreeWidgets

Tags: qt, pyqt, styling

When I change the application style to the windows style I get these dotted index lines with all my QTreeWidgets. I have to use the windows style due to Mac creating issues when I do not use it.

[image: lines]

You can replicate this by creating a treewidget and setting the application style to "Windows"

Comment: Those are "branch lines" used to show the tree structure. For top level items, see the [`rootIsDecorated`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#rootIsDecorated-prop) property, but I'm actually curious about your statement, as you might be doing this for the wrong reasons: "I have to use the windows style due to Mac creating issues when I do not use it.". What issues?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087045/hide-mac-specific-buttons-on-lists-pyqt

Comment: Using a completely different style that is not consistent with the OS only because you didn't find a proper solution to an issue related to a customization doesn't seem a good approach, so you *are* doing the above for the wrong reason.

Comment: That was the solution I could find. And it was also the solution other people were using.

Comment: It *could* be a bug, in that case it should be reported. But since I've seen custom styling working perfectly fine on combo boxes on MacOS, that doesn't seem the case, and it's more likely that there was some issue in the configuration of the combo and/or wrong stylesheets were set. As already requested in the comments to that post, you should provide a proper [mre], and eventually point out the resources you found out claiming about that being the only solution.